# Interceptor for Weceem Security rules

Tags: security, weceem

We managed to install weceem plugin and could map with user roles. But we need more control as follow. There are tenants in the system, users of which have the same roles. But each tenant in the grails app is fully isolated from other tenants. So we plan to create one space for each tenant. Then we want to grant access for users of one tenant to their specific wecem space. This way users of one tenant can't access the content of another SPACE meant for another tenant. We can't isolate based on roles, because users of all tetants will have same role - like 'Tenant Admin'.

1. Can we write an intercptor in the controller (or somewhere else) which will be invoked by the security framework, and we want to write custom code in that intercptor to determine that the tenant is accessing only his specific SPACE and that allow access, else deny ?
2. can we create SPACE progamatically from the main application ? like, when a tenant is created in the system, we want to create a SPACE for him.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default weceem-security bridge (weceem-spring-security plugin) that defines user management system between application and weceem. You can implement your own security decision that takes tenants into account and define credentials to the specified Space. Check the weceem-security plugin sources to get the ideas https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-spring-security/ . According to second question -  you can create Space programmatically from the application if you need.